# How and what would I get from a car rain sensor?

Tags: sensor, obd

I am looking for an answer on how to acquire data for the vehicle rain sensor and automatic wiper data from any vehicle.

For example, I know that with Carberry (a Raspberry Pi) it provides a lot of OBD features. However, I cannot seem to find anything on acquiring data for rain sensor, precipitation, wiper frequency, wiper speed...

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I don't think this is a very good fit for this forum. I'm transferring it to the Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair forum, which has an explicit `odb-ii` tag.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about motor vehicle maintenance and repair.

Comment: We get many questions regarding OBD readers here @DavidSupportsMonica, so this seems very on-topic to me.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get this type of data from OBD. Wiper speed is a function of the motor rotation, the design of the wiper mechanism and arms, and you will have different velocities at the inner and outer end of the arms.

Comment: As GdD said, most of this data is not usually available through OBD. If you wish to get data from sensors that are not provided on the bus would be to intercept the signal yourself. So some skill in electronics is likely to be needed.